# Apache virtualhost permission denied with several different DocumentRoots tried. What should I try next?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a self compiled version of Apache 2 running under Mac OS X Leopard. It's a default install at /usr/local/apache2 and work fine.

Today I wanted to add a virtual host so I could access a particular folder with the domain name `http://binarytales.local`

So I added `127.0.0.1 binarytales.local` to `/etc/hosts`, fluch the dns cache and, yey, I could access my server via that address.

I wanted to be able to access, via my newly created local domain name, a subfolder in in my working web server. So I set up the following vhosts file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ProjectX
    ServerName binarytales.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Browsing to `localhost` works fine, I get the files I always used to get. Browsing to `binarytales.local` gives me an internal server error.

I did a bit of investgating and discovered that I had set htdocs to be a symlink to `/Users/me/Sites` so I tried setting my vhost to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/me/Sites/ProjectX
    ServerName binarytales.local
</VirtualHost>
```

This didn't work either. Now I'm getting `Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

So I tried `DocumentRoot /Users/me/Sites` and got the same forbidden message.

Finally I have tried

DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs2
        ServerName binarytales.local

Where `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs2` is a symlink to `Users/me/Sites/ProjectX`. And I also tried it with `Users/me/Sites`. I'm getting the same "Forbidden" error.

I have checked the user and group settings on everything is root/wheel apart from the stuff in `Users/me/Sites/' which is me/wheel. All the directors are chmod -x for everyone.

I'm totally stuck and don't have a clue what to try next!

---

My question title is crap. Please do change it to/suggest something better.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so I fixed this about 5 mins later by putting this

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/Binarytales">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks  
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

inside my virtualhost declaration. so in the end it read as thus:

NameVirtualHost *:80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/Binarytales
    ServerName binarytales.local

    <Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/Binarytales">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I think the magic juice here is `Options ... FollowSymLinks` but it anyone has a good explanation as to why this works then please let me know, or if there is a better/alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would have tried a `bind` mount first. Presuming it works on Mac OS X like it does on Linux:

```
mount --bind /path/one /path/two
```